# Image inside table make it go overflow even with height blocked on 100%

Tags: html, css, web

I'm going crazy, I have my website(http://piscagliacostruzioni.it/) divided by three frames(three rows), in the first one I have a table as menu, it uses around the 30 % of height of the screen.
In this table i put some images, the table is set to 100% to fit the frame and the image are set to fit the cell(only in height, i don't care about width) so what i was expecting was the image to fit in height without overflow, but the result is the image going out of the frame from the bottom and not being displayed.

Here is an example: `https://jsfiddle.net/danipisca07/g0dpr0cL/`

(I used a div to simulate the frame as parent)

```
<div style="height : 10%">
<table style="height: 100%; table-layout:fixed">
    <tr height="65%">
        <img src="http://piscagliacostruzioni.it/scrittariga.jpg" style="height:100%"/>
    </tr>
    <tr heigth="35%">
        <img src="http://piscagliacostruzioni.it/Contatti/contatti.jpg" style="height:100%"/>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Tried to set the table-layout to fixed and the image display property to block but everything was useless.

I hope you will help.
Thanks in advance
Bye

Comment: Your code is missing <td>

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all the answers, I noticed only now I forget the td tag anyway on the testing i'm doing on my computer I didn't forget it so that's not the problem.
On the site the code it's different because with the table I didn't find a way to autoresize the images to fit in height so I fixed the problem giving the images a fixed height in pixels but now I want to use a table to autoresize the image to fit,I tested what said by gopalraju but the problem isn't solved. Look here: https://jsfiddle.net/danipisca07/g0dpr0cL/3/
Continue....

Comment: On jfiddle if you try to reduce the div height(let's say to set it at 10%) the image will be anyway around the 30% of the space. But if you set the height higher than the 40/50% it works perfectly.... Thanks again for your time guys

Comment: I think it's because CSS can extend the image to reach the 100% height but for some reason it can't reduce it if the image is bigger than the 100%...possible?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/g0dpr0cL/2/

1. Your code is missing `<td>`
2. All parent elements (including `html` and `body`) needs a height.

   html,body{
       height:100%
   }

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved the problem(almost), instead of the first row of the table I used only the image and under it a table with only one row. To understand better see my website: piscagliacostuzioni.it, i've already uploaded the new solution.
Thanks again guys

Answer (score 0):

I think your main issue is that you're missing the `<td></td>` elements from inside the `<tr></tr>` elements.

`<tr>...</tr>` is a table-row.

`<td>...</td>` is a table-data (the columns inside a row)

So having two rows will ALWAYS wrap the second image onto a second line - that's what the rows are for.

I'm not 100% sure if I understand the layout you're trying to achieve, but try the following code:

```
<div>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://piscagliacostruzioni.it/scrittariga.jpg" style="width:100%;"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="http://piscagliacostruzioni.it/Contatti/contatti.jpg" style="width:100%;"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: infact thats the layout the would be more natural and intuitive for me but it didn't work(see comment on first post)